# overflow-y: scroll is cutting of background color

Tags: html, css

I have a trello-like interface that I'm writing. I am trying to have an element with overflow-y be a parent to my lists. However, my background color is getting cut off at the height of the list's parent element.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image: Closeup]

CSS for parent:

```
.parent {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 80vh;
}
```

CSS for child (list)

```
.list {
    background-color: #F5F6F6;
    min-width: 275px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: initial;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: why restrict the height of the parent?

Comment: design choice, however that could be a solution. I would prefer to keep it this way though.

Comment: the children overflow the parent's container because of the height restriction. You could either move the background-color up one level in your markup or prevent the overflow with `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: hidden;` scroll would show two scrollbars though which could be an issue depending on design.

Comment: I see that the child overflows, but why does the child's background color not overflow? That's my issue.

Comment: oh whoops, I think I misunderstood the problem :) What does your markup look like?

Comment: It is in JSX, so ignore the syntax. https://pastebin.com/BUSgPjhx

Comment: You'd try put `overflow-y: hidden;` in **.parent** and `overflow: auto;` in **list**

Comment: could you share the html please, could you paste on https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 0):

set the min-width to specific length or 100% then add width with 'fit-content' value
e.g

```
.parent {
    overflow: auto/scroll;
}
.child {
    min-width: 100%/45px;
    width: fit-content;
}
```